# How to handle ConstraintLayout horizontal & vertical with view.GONE

Tags: java, android, visibility, android-constraintlayout

already use vertical and horizontal chain in constraint for handle visibility gone. But they are not enought for the thing i want to do.
I need to set a view like this example:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

And, for example, when i set number 2 to visibility GONE, the number 3 has to take his place.

I try to do something like this, but im not even close..

```
`<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/paymentCardQR"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/paymentCardEfectivo"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/paymentCardTarjeta"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/paymentCardEfectivo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/red"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/paymentCardCtaCliente"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/paymentCardVoucher"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/paymentCardQR">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/paymentCardCtaCliente"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/green"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/paymentCardOnline"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/paymentCardEfectivo">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/paymentCardTarjeta"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/paymentCardVoucher"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/paymentCardQR"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/paymentCardVoucher"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/paymentCardOnline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/paymentCardEfectivo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/paymentCardTarjeta">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/paymentCardOnline"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/paymentCardCtaCliente"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/paymentCardVoucher">

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not applicable with `ConstraintLayout` I'm afraid, you should use `RecyclerView` with each view in a separate item while using `GridLayoutManager` as its layout manger with 2 spans.

When the list is built the number of items can be controlled through its adapter using `notifyItemRemoved(1)` to remove or `notifyItemInserted(1)` to add the item smoothly with animations. Or you can easily call `notifyDataSetChanged()` for a full but not performant adapter update after you have changed your data set.

Comment: Thankz for the help, i finaly use recycler view, want to do it with constraint, but i see there is no way.